# Comparing the difference between two keys Not using CompareTo java

Tags: java, compare, key

other than using compareTo which only returns values -1, 0 and 1 and therefore cant be used for this situation,

is there a way to compare the difference between keys?

example `Key A = 5 Key B = 7 and Key C = 10`

(I use numbers in the example for simplicity, I when I run the test code I will not know if the keys are numbers or strings.)

```
C - B  = 3
C - A = 5
```

the difference between Key C and B is smaller  so Key B is closer to C

is there a method in a Java library for this? (I have checked quite a bit) Or are we on our own? Can we subtract the difference between keys?

Comment: "implementing" subtraction doesn't sound like a big deal to me...

Comment: Java does not support such a feature.

Comment: thanks @user3707125 thats what I thought, I'll have to figure a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

MyClass a=new MyClass(5);
MyClass b =new MyClass(7);
MyClass c =new MyClass(10);

MyClass result=c.closerTo(a,b);

}

interface Closer<T> {
 T closerTo(T t1,T t2);
}

class MyClass implements Closer<MyClass>{

private Integer num;

public MyClass(Integer n) {
 num=n;
}

@Override
public MyClass closerTo(MyClass t1, MyClass t2) {

 Integer diff1=num-t1.num;
 Integer diff2=num-t2.num;
 return diff1<diff2?t1:t2;

 }

}
```